# How to show that $pm/pn=m/n$ and that $pm \bmod pn = p(m \bmod n)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I'm sure I'm overly thinking this but I'm stuck and I need help just starting the following problem: 
Show that for any natural number $m$, any positive natural number $n$ & any positive natural number $p$, it is the case that $pm/pn=m/n$ and that $pm \bmod pn = p(m \bmod n)$?

Comment: Does $m/n$ designate a rational number, or does it denote the integer quotient (dropping the remainder)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you are talking about Euclidean division. Then $m/n=q$ and $m\bmod n=r$ mean exactly that $m=qn+r$ and $0\leq r<n$. Multiplying by $p$ one deduces that $pm=qpn+pr$ and $0\leq pr<pn$, which can be read as $pm/pn=q$ and $pn\bmod pn=pr$, which is what you wanted to prove.

Comment: Ok that's what I pretty much did but thought it was missing steps or too short! Thank you for clarifying!